# How to try AWS Appsync in local sam

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync, aws-serverless

so i have a doubt, about to AppsSync and SAM, and is if i can run the api graphQl in local sam? if is so, what i need to do it, but, without dynamodb?, else i would like know which is the best practices to do a test or approach, on appSync.

because the examples that i read, all it's on aws account with dynamodb and assembly, and i want to try it on sam local without dynamo and without assembly.

so i try this basic configuration at the template.yaml, that i found, on this repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/sbstjn/appsync-resolvers-example/blob/master/template.yml)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  graphql

  Sample SAM Template for graphql

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
plugins:
  - serverless-appsync-plugin
  - serverless-webpack
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
  
  Role: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: appsync.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: allow-access-to-lambda-from-appsync
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement: 
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: lambda:invokeFunction
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt [ HelloWorldFunction, Arn ]
                  - !Join [ '', [ !GetAtt [ HelloWorldFunction, Arn ], ':*' ] ]

  AppSyncAPI:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Join [ -, [ !Ref ParamProjectName, !Ref ParamENV ] ]
      AuthenticationType: API_KEY

  AppSyncSchema:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt [ AppSyncAPI, ApiId ]
      DefinitionS3Location: schema.graphql

  AppSyncDataSource:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::DataSource
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt [ AppSyncAPI, ApiId ]
      Name: handler
      Type: AWS_LAMBDA
      LambdaConfig:
        LambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt [ HelloWorldFunction, Arn ]
      ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt [ Role, Arn ]



  AppSyncReolverPeople:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::reolver
    properties: 
      ApiId: !GetAtt [AppSyncAPI, ApiId]
      TypeName: Query
      FieldName: !GetAtt [AppSyncDataSource, Name]
      RequestMappingTemplate:
        '
        {
          "version":"2017-02-28",
          "operation": "Invoke",
          "payload":{
            "resolve":"query.people",
            "context":"$utils.toJson($context)"
          }
        }
        '
    ResponseMappingTemplate: $util.toJson($context.result)

  AppSyncAPIKey:
      Type: AWS::AppSync::ApiKey
      Properties:
        ApiId: !GetAtt [ AppSyncAPI, ApiId ]
        Expires: !Ref ParamKeyExpiration

Parameters:

  ParamProjectName:
    Type: String
  ParamENV:
    Type: String
  ParamKeyExpiration:
    Type: Number
     

Outputs:
  APIKey:
      Description: API Key
      Value: !GetAtt [ AppSyncAPIKey, ApiKey ]

  GraphQL:
    Description: GraphQL URL
    Value: !GetAtt [ AppSyncAPI, GraphQLUrl ]
```

this is the schema.graphql

```
type Person {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    age: Int!

    friends: [Person!]!
}

type Query {
    people: [Person!]!
    person(id: Int): Person!
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

and this is the lambda code:

```
 import json




def lambda_handler(event, context):

    data={
        "id":1
        "name":"milse",
        "age":12
    }
    if event.name==data.name:
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": " hi :" + data.name
             
        }),
    }
    else:
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": " the name is not here" 
             
        }),
    }
```

so i thanks you, for your help.

Comment: Hey @alejandro, have you found a good way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way to test AppSync locally:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-local-mocking/

SAM does not support it.

Comment: The resource you shared walks through an AppSync API that was initialized with Amplify.I know SAM does not support local invocations, but if the AppSync API was created with SAM is there a way to only use Amplify for testing purposes but not for any of the build or deploy process?

Comment: hey @portatlas I am also wondering if it's possible, have you found out a good way to do this? If your suggestion is impossible, I think only one way is to write integration tests per each query/mutation against remote AppSync API instead of mocking local AppSync.

Comment: @AnatoliiB No, I haven't figured out a good way forward for this.